# In App purchase price country wise currency conversion

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, currency

In my android app, I have in app purchase. I used Indian gateway and it is working fine for payments in INR. Since I m planning to release it outside India, so how would I convert price for each country against valid conversion on day of sale of service. I referred few links but did not get any idea to start with. pls guide.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Android handles this for you.

Refer to https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing

> Provide a price in your home currency, or link the price to an
>   existing pricing template. Based on the price you enter or the prices
>   from the pricing template, the system autofills country-specific
>   prices for different currencies. These generated prices use current
>   exchange rates and locally relevant pricing patterns (see figure 1).
>   You can also change prices for other currencies manually, but you can
>   do this only if a currency is used in one of the target countries for
>   your app. You can specify target countries for your app on the Pricing
>   & Distribution page in the Google Play Developer Console.